# If $\mathop {\max }\limits_{{{\left\| x \right\|}_2} = 1} {\left\| {Ax} \right\|_2} = 0$, why must $A$ be zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose

- $A \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}}$
- $\left\| A \right\| = \mathop {\max }\limits_{{{\left\| x \right\|}_2} = 1} {\left\| {Ax} \right\|_2}$
- $\left\| A \right\| = 0$

Is this true that $A=0$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please always include some English words in the question title, so that on right-click, the browser's context menu is not overridden by the MathJax menu.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's true. For this to see you can do the following, denote $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^t$ and $e_i=(0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)^t$ etc, then you have
$$
\left\|e_i\right\|_2=1 \text{ and } Ae_i=(a_{1,i},\ldots,a_{n,i})^t 
$$
and you know already that 
$$
\mathop {\max }\limits_{{{\left\| x \right\|}_2} = 1} {\left\| {Ax} \right\|_2}=0
$$
so you have
$$
\left\|Ae_i\right\|=\left\|(a_{1,i},\ldots,a_{n,i})^t \right\|_2=0
$$
which means that 
$$
\forall 1\leq i\leq n:a_{1,i}=\ldots=a_{n,i}=0
$$
and this means $A\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\|Ax\|_2 =\sqrt{x^TA^TAx}.$$
Let, $B=A^TA$, is a symmetric PSD matrix, so all the eigen values of $B$, $\lambda_1, \ \lambda_2, \ \dots \ , \ \lambda_n \geq 0.$
$$B = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i q_i q_i^T$$
$$\|Ax\|_2=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(q_i^Tx)^2}$$

So, the maximum value of $\|Ax\|_2$ should be greater than equal to $0$. As, the maxmium value is $0 \ \forall \ \|x\|_2 =1,$ so only possibility is all the $\lambda_i$s are zero. So, $A=0_{n\times n}.$

Comment: in your first line it should be the square root of the scalarproduct...

Comment: Ya. It's true. Its a silly miss. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a norm includes that $\lVert A \rVert = 0$ implies $A = \mathbf{0}$.

See property #2 for the definition of norm on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)

Answer (score 1):

We must have that $||Ax||_2 = 0$ for all $x$ of norm $1$.

Any vector $v$ can be written as $v=cx$, where $c$ is a scalar, and $x$ has norm $1$, and thus $||Av||_2 = |c|\cdot||Ax||_2 = 0$ for all $v$. Since $||\cdot||_2$ is a norm, this implies that $Av=0$ for all $v$, and thus that $A=0$.